# Strange error with GnuPG: claims "no secret key" when terminal is too small

Tags: terminal, gpg, ncurses, pinentry

This is the content of my `.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
```

When I try to retrieve a password from `pass`' store, e.g. via `pass -c path/to/password` in a very small-sized terminal window, the command errors like this:

```
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

So it's an error from GnuPG, caused, I believe, by not enough space for ncurses to draw the pinentry dialog.

Can anybody reproduce this? If so, where can I report this bug?

[image]

Comment: You can get information about packages from your package manager. Eg if you're in a debianlike distro such as ubuntu you could `apt-cache show gnupg`. It gives both the package homepage and a link for filing bug reports. Btw your question isn't really about gnupg, it is about "How to find where to file bug reports?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you report a (suspected) bug, you should state the behavior you observe and what you expected instead. So in this case, and as you opened a bug report with GnuPG, you should state what you think should happen. If you add it here, you should edit the question, not add it only in a comment. See also the suggestions at the bottom.

Yes, this happens because the window is too small. It also doesn't originate from GnuPG: GnuPG just calls the `pinentry-program` you specified in the configuration.

For details about what happens, we can try to call it manually.

```
$ stty cols 20 rows 10
$ pinentry-curses 
OK Pleased to meet you
GETPIN
S ERROR curses.dialog_create 83886381 
ERR 83886381 Screen or window too small <Pinentry>
```

Here I first made the tty size small and then called `pinentry-curses`. It waits for a command, I typed `GETPIN`, the command to acquire the PIN. It complains that the screen is too small to display the dialog. GnuPG just reports that it can't get the PIN.

I saw what you wrote it the ticket, but what you propose is between difficult and impossibly, because `gpg` should not care about terminal size, and therefor should not claim that the terminal is too small.

Instead I would suggest the following text (I don't want to create an account there):

`gpg` calls the `pinentry-program` if it needs to decrypt a key. It would be better for the user if `pgp` wouldn't display the generic message
`decryption failed: No secret key`
and instead forwarded the message from the `pinentry-program`, something like:
`Can't decrypt key, pinentry-program failed with (text from ERR response)`.

Additionally, if `pinentry-curses` is maintained by the gpg team, it could detect a small windows and behave the same as when `$TERM` is unset, avoiding this error.

Comment: Ok, but the error I get is `gpg: ...`, so at least `gpg` is catching the exception (?) bubbling up from pinentry and it's forwarding it to the terminal with an unrelated error message. I've opened the bug report [T5322](https://dev.gnupg.org/T5322).

Comment: @Enlico `pgp` is just reporting the error. Exception is not the correct term here. As you have opened a bug, please also include an expected behavior (in the bug, not here). My suggestion would be that `pgp` should print the message received by the pinentry program, such as `Operation cancelled` (the message when user selects cancel) or `Screen or window too small`. Also, `pinentry-curses` with a small window could behave as with unset `$TERM`.

Comment: @RalfFriedl, I've commented in the bug report, as you suggested.